# Load Image from binary

Tags: c#, html

This is my loop for loading images from Binary[] (SqlServerCe). Each image is stored in a list holding a byte array:

```
List<byte[]> imgBinary = new List<byte[]>();
```

The imgMIME variable contains values like:

```
image/png
image/bmp
```

and so on.

My current code looks like this:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < infos.Count(); i++)
{
    <li>    
        @lat[i], 
        @lon[i], 
        @infos[i],
        <img src="data:'+'@imgMIME[i]'+';base64{'+'@imgBinary[i]'+'}"/>
    </li>
}
```

On my page i get an error image for each of these loaded images. 
May someone please help me solve this out?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your inline image formatting is incorrect - it should be:

```
data:MIMETYPE;base64,CONTENT_AS_BASE64_STRING
```

There should be no curly braces (*{* and *}*) in the string. You can read more about inline images in [this article](http://www.websiteoptimization.com/speed/tweak/inline-images/).

It looks like you are writing the bytes to the inline image. An inline image works when the content is given as [Base64 formatted string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). That is why you need to convert your image content to a Base64 string (your current content is in a byte array) using [Convert.ToBase64String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dhx0d524%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I would also suggest you to use [String.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<img src=@string.Format("data:{0};base64,{1}", imgMIME[i], Convert.ToBase64String(imgBinary[i]))/>
```

IMO it approves readability and thus it's easier to see the correct string. An example of working inline image:

```
<img src="data:image\png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAYAAABzenr0AAAABHNCSVQICAgIfAhkiAAAAAlwSFlzAAALEgAACxIB0t1+/AAAABZ0RVh0Q3JlYXRpb24gVGltZQAwOC8xOC8wOaw6EPwAAAAcdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAEFkb2JlIEZpcmV3b3JrcyBDUzQGstOgAAACEElEQVRYhcWXQY7TMBSGPyM2SEgUiT25wWRO0CCxeV5xA+YGzA2mF0DM7NjRI7B6b5uROECHFTvCBaCVEEvCIjYKaZraBdpfip7y/GJ/ebZfHNe2LafU/Zxg7/0P4AGwAVbBXQe7AtZAo6pNap8uNQPe+xnwDfgOPEx4ZBfkE+CTqn6AvAyUwb5W1UWAKoFZuMpeXPTNg2/OtlwuQBVsfCtUddVrf7/rQe99fLYA3gI/f1PEKRCRyblwzgGQOmVm5kZACuAzcKuqFcC9pN7+nYpg6+jYmoIx8hztyWQVbBMdx85AXKgnAygAVLU+FcAZ8KXvyAYQkdkhI4eaAb30ZwOIyIKJ/b5HEaA+CEBELoArYC4iywMAimD7xSsNIAz+rud6eQBEFWyTBSAil4PB+xB1xpooYat8TwOIyDXwZiJkzmBOxxS+pI+Au2HbTgARKYFX+zoHzkKWpjS6AyYBgBcJg6fGRoDVsGEKYD3iu6MrJJuE2L8GWPLnnN3Q1YA13RtHiA2w2ANQZAOY2drMSuAceGxml8AFXTltzGwGnJvZzMy2Oh5oDjB2Vtx7Ioqdh4X2lO6Nl0CVMHC/BN+OtScfyczsGrhOje+pCLYZazzG13DnFoTM/4JUOefw3i/oFt3z4K6PBhB0Nbj/ejSAtm1xzj0LtxWAqn4ci00+lucq9XB77CPZlpL/Df+XTp6BXyWzqYOyhB+rAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" />
```

It looks like this:

[image: inline image output]

Have a look at your html source in the image element. It you don't see such text but only numbers, then the content is not beeing written as base64 string.

Comment: Thank you for your answert but still I got the same error image. Don't you know why ?

Comment: What is your error exactly? Extend your question with the error text and also give one of the images content in order to check if content is ok.

Comment: I changed/extended the code from my answer. Give it a try and tell me if it works now. I have forgotten to tell you, that the inline image content should be as Base64 string and to convert your byte[] to base64string.